# Where do I view my CronJob in OpenShift Container Platform?

Tags: kubernetes, cron, openshift, redhat

This is a really basic question, that I just can't seem to find it ANYWHERE.
I need to create a **CronJob on OpenShift Container Platform**.

I wasn't able to find a page on the Container Platform on how to directly create a CronJob.

But I did manage to find instruction on creating it by pasting the Job yaml file in the **Add to Application** Button.
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/nodes/jobs/nodes-nodes-jobs.html

Now, having created a **CronJob**(I think).

Lol, how do I even **find/modify/delete** it on **Container Platform**?

Comment: You can refer to the v3 documentation: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html. It should still be relevant to v4

Comment: @WillGordon Hi, yes I've seen it for creation of CronJob but is there an interface on the Container Platform to view our job? How do I debug if I did incorrectly?
And we deploy via Jenkins, so we do not have anywhere to input OC commands.

Comment: In the web console for 4.x, there's a section under Workloads > Cron Jobs that should show you what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Openshift version 3.X, you need to be under "Administrator" profile. Then click Workloads/Cronjobs.

Answer (score 3):

You can find cron jobs in the `Cluster Console/Workloads/Cron Jobs`.